# Xamarin.iOS: how to open Wallet/Apple Pay app?

Tags: xamarin.ios, deep-linking, applepay, wallet

I work on Xamarin app allowing users to manage payment cards.

I would like to know it is possible to open the Wallet/Apple Pay app from my app?

For the moment, I don't need that users can add directly their cards: this should be done later. I just need a "link" from my app to the Wallet/ApplePay app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an unpublished schema `shoebox://`  that you can use to open Wallet.

It is possible to open directly to a particular card, if you know the Pass Type Certificate ID, the pass Serial Number, and the hashing algorithm.

Unfortunately, the latter can only be found by decompiling the Wallet app, but it's pretty easy to find if you know what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.
Can this be used in a Xamarin app?
For the moment, I don't need to open a particular card, but just to open  the Wallet app.

Comment: Yes - just using with `shoebox://` as your URL should work.  If not, you could try explicitly calling `UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("shoebox://"));`